# Simple Jquery photo gallery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a very simple photo gallery with html5 and jquery. The gallery work good sliding the pictures sequential using 2 arrow botton, but The difficult for me is to reach a photo directly from its thumbnail. Someone can help me?

The system work in this way:

HTML (THUMBNAIL 1,2,3) i need to link these to set visible their big version on gallery

```
<img src="img/gallery/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" id="thumb1"/>
<img src="img/gallery/2.jpg" style="width:100%; id="thumb1"/>
<img src="img/gallery/3.jpg" style="width:100%;" id="thumb1"/>
```

HTML(IMGSLIDE AND CONTROL ARROW)

```
<img src="img/gallery/1.jpg" id="galleryimages">
<img onclick="slide(-1)" src="img/gallery/leftarrow.png" id="gallerybutton">
 <img onclick="slide(1)" src="img/gallery/leftarrow.png" id="gallerybutton">
```

SCRIPT

```
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 9;

function slide(x) {
var image = document.getElementById('galleryimages');
imagecount = imagecount + x;
if (imagecount > total){ imagecount = 1; }
if (imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total; }
image.src = "img/gallery/" + imagecount + ".jpg";
imagecount = imagecount 
};
```

Comment: Think to ha solved in this way resetting the imagecount value to 1 each times I click on the thumbnail:
     <a href="#"  id="thisphoto" onclick="1"><img src="img/gallery/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" id="thumb1"/></a>
 <a href="#"  id="thisphoto" onclick="2"><img src="img/gallery/2.jpg" style="width:100%;" id="thumb1"/></a>


SCRIPT


$('#thisfoto).click(function(e){  
  imagecount = null; 
  imagecount = 1 ; 
    $('#galleryslide').fadeIn(1000) };

Comment: One problem with your HTML, you have multiple elements with the same `id`. `id`s must be unique. To identify a type of thing as you are, you should be using classes instead.

Comment: Look at my answer, It work good and it's very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the same gallery script I've solved this action with a the gallery opening system. I've add to any thumbnails a link who set the function slide with is photo number -1. So here a simple photo gallery. Now I need to reset the value of the imagecount var when I close a photo to open the correct clicked foto after. So I've added a script on click of a close button to reset the imagecount variabLe

THUMBNAILS:

```
<a href="#" onclik="slide(0)" id="opg">
<img src="img/gallery/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" id="thumb1"/>
</a>
<a href="#" onclik="slide(1)" id="opg2">
<img src="img/gallery/2.jpg" style="width:100%;" id="thumb2"/>
</a>
<a href="#" onclik="slide(2)" id="opg3">
<img src="img/gallery/3.jpg" style="width:100%;" id="thumb3"/>
</a>
```

GALLERY OPENED

```
<img src="img/gallery/1.jpg" id="galleryimages"><!--gallery-->
<a href="#" onclick="slide(-1)"> Previous </a><!--previctures link-->
<a href="#" onclick="slide(-1)"> Next </a><!--nextctures link-->
<a href="#" id="closegallery">Close</a><!--closebutton-->
```

OPEN AND CLOSE GALLERY

```
$('#opg,#opg2,#opg3').click(function(e){     
$('#galleryimages').fadeIn(1000) });  //open gallery clicking tmbn


//close gallery clicking the close button and reset imagecount to 1
$('#closegallery').click(function(e){ 
imagecount = null; 
imagecount = 1 ;     
$('#galleryimages').fadeOut(1000) });
```

GALLERY SYSTEM

```
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 9;

function slide(x) {
var image = document.getElementById('galleryimages');
imagecount = imagecount + x;
if (imagecount > total){ imagecount = 1; }
if (imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total; }
image.src = "img/gallery/" + imagecount + ".jpg";
imagecount = imagecount 
};
```